# How to show component inside another dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have a component `LayersComponent`.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-layers",
  templateUrl: "./layers.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./layers.component.sass"]
})
export class LayersComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

Template is:

```
<div class="Layers">
  Text

  <!-- Create component below -->
  <app-another-component></app-another-component>
</div>
```

I want to create and show dinamically component `<app-another-component></app-another-component>` inside current component.

But I need send command create from another component not inside `LayersComponent`, but somewhere from another component in application.

How to do that?

I have tried:

```
<div class="Layers">
   Text
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="app-another-component"></ng-container>
</div>
```

But I dont know how to send command outside `LayersComponent`?

Comment: By "command" do you mean the html content that should be injected?

Comment: No, somewhre in compnent I have `(click)="creatComponentAnotherInsideComponnet()"`. others words I need to know from where component I create component and where I palce it

Comment: by click in component 1 I need create component 2 and place it inside component 500, something like this

Comment: You can use a `Subject` to let the components communicate an put an `ngIf` to programmatically render the component you want

Comment: Is it good practic? Could I use FactoryComponent to set what compoent should be reproduce? (in which components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ComponentFactoryResolver` in Angular to handle dynamic loader for multiple components:

Here is sample code:

```js
import {
    Component,
    ComponentFactory,
    ComponentRef,
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    ViewContainerRef,
    ViewChild
} from '@angular/core'
import { AComponent } from './a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal-resolver',
    template: `
        <template #modalContainer></template>
    `,
})
export class ModalResolver {
    @ViewChild("modalContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container;
    @Input() name;
    componentRef: ComponentRef;

    listComponent: {
        'modalA': AComponent,
        'modalB': BComponent
    }

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadComponent(this.name);
    }
    loadComponent(type) {
        this.container.clear();
        const factory: ComponentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.listComponent[this.name]);

        this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);

        this.componentRef.instance.type = type;

        this.componentRef.instance.output.subscribe(event => console.log(event));

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentRef.destroy();
    }
}
```

Then you use it:

```
<modal-resolver name="modalA"></modal-resolver>
```

You can read more from Angular document:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Excellent, so anywhere I need to creatr component I use `<modal-resolver name="modalA"></modal-resolver>`. And I tell which component to create: `modalA`. But if I place `<modal-resolver name="modalA"></modal-resolver>` into existing component. It creates `modalA`, but I need to create this by event (emit) from anothre component. Someone recommends to use Subject() for that

Comment: What is difference from `<modalA *ngIf="type == 'modalA"></modalA>`

Comment: ComponentFactory  and ComponentRef needs to specify type

Comment: Subject is a good one. But this is simple thing to do, So I recommend you to use object which defines many common components (related to one business) and change that data base on event emitter. Could you check this sample?https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxxrnnbvxned?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

The solution for the simple case of injecting HTML content is to use `<ng-content>`.

**parent**

```
<child>
  <p>Some injected HTML content</p>
</child>
```

**child**

```
<p>
  <!-- inner HTML of <child> will go here -->
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</p>
```

## **ngTemplateOutlet**

If you want to dynamically inject the HTML, you just dynamically declare the HTML inside `<child>`:

**parent**

```
<child>
  <p *ngIf="condition1">Some conditional injected HTML content</p>
  <p *ngIf="condition2">Some different conditional injected HTML content</p>
</child>
```

You would use `ngTemplateOutlet` if you want to reference a named template:

**parent**

```
<child>
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="body"></ng-container>
</child>

<ng-template #body>
  <p>Some reusable content</p>
</ng-template>
```

## **Targetting injected HTML**

To target specific parts of the injected HTML, use selectors:

**parent**

```
<child>
  <span heading>TITLE</span>
  <p body>The body</p>
</child>
```

**child**

```
<h1><ng-content select="[heading]"></ng-content></h1>
<div select="[body]">

</div>
```

Comment: Let me explain again I have compoennt that I want to insert to another one compoennt in applicaion. By click. It should be dinamically

Comment: If the click is in the parent, then the parent can decide what content is injected into the child

Comment: I dont have parent I have any component where I do click and somewhere I need to create component, no matter what is component. Just there is `component A` that shoud be added into component B, C, D, or any one. How to contrl this proccess?

Comment: You need a shared service then. Button clicks that trigger some change in state call a subject in a service, and components that choose what HTML to display subscribe to this subject and render the correct HTML.

Comment: I would be duplicating plenty of answers by going into detail about how you would set up a shared service.

Comment: I got you, you recommend to use Subject. Send message to crete component and somewhere in place where I need reproduce component, I just subscribe on event and create dinamically component, right?

Comment: I reckon you've got it.